# How to declare the variable File.byLine() is assigned to?

Tags: d

I need a class or struct which would look something like

```
struct ThingReader {
    ???? lines;
    Thing thing;

    this(File f) {
        this.lines = f.byLine;
        popFront;
    }

    @property bool empty()      { return lines.empty; }
    @property ref Thing front() { return thing; }
    void popFront() {
        if (! empty) {
            auto l = lines.front;
            lines.popFront;
            parseLine(l, thing); // Not shown
        }
    }
}
```

but I don't know what type declaration to put in place where the ???? is.

If I try `auto lines` then the error is "Error: no identifier for declarator lines".

If I leave the type-inference to the compiler and try something like:

```
struct ThingReader(Lines) {
    Lines lines;
    Thing thing;

    this(File f) {
        this.lines = f.byLine;
        popFront;
    }
    // etc.
}
```

then the compiler seems to be fine with this declaration, but when I later try to declare an `auto reader = ThingReader(f)`, I get
"Error: struct huh.ThingReader cannot deduce function from argument types !()(File)".

The File.byLine function is declared to return `auto` but that (see above) does
not work for me.

When I declare an `auto lines = f.byLine` and inspect its type, I can see
that it is a `ByLine!(char, char)`.
When I try to declare a `ByLine lines`, I get "Error: undefined identifier ByLine"
and when I try to declare a `std.stdio.ByLine lines`, I get
"Error: undefined identifier ByLine in module std.stdio".
When I try to declare a `ByLine!(char, char)`, I get "Error: template
instance ByLine!(char, char) template 'ByLine' is not defined", and
`std.stdio.ByLine!(char, char)` gives me "Error: template identifier
'ByLine' is not a member of module 'std.stdio'".

Comment: try `typeof(File.byLine) lines;` as your variable declaration. it might work

Comment: Thank you, but compile fails with "Error: variable app.LineRange.lines variables cannot be of type void" when I try that.
The `typeof` spec pages says "If the expression is a Property Function, typeof gives its return type.", so I guess `File.byLine` is not a property function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned by Adam in the comments, you can use `typeof(File.byLine())` to deduce the type you want; it is necessary to add the final parenthesis, which is why `typeof(File.byLine)` does not work.
The reason you cannot explicitly give the type for `lines` is because the struct returned by the `byLine` function is private, so cannot be referenced from outside the `std.stdio` module.

Comment: This does the trick utterly and completely. I would not have thought to call an instance method as a class method.
Thank you.